# How do I zero out or remove the water filter count, other than changing the filter?

Tags: water, filter

GE fridge model # GFE28GYNGFS —-

Answer (score 4):

According to GE manual

Push and hold the water button for 3 seconds untill you hear a sound that indicates it was reset.

Page 17

[GE Manual](https://products.geappliances.com/MarketingObjectRetrieval/Dispatcher?RequestType=PDF&Name=49-1000585-4_LoRes.pdf)